# Table 'DBName.user' doesn't exist when trying to change root user name

Tags: mysql

I have just installed MySQL on Debian 7.0.0.

I successfully imported by database from another system using

```
mysql -u root -p DBName <mysql27May13.dump
```

I then successfully logged onto MySQL using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I then successfully selected the database using

```
use DBName;
```

Also

```
show tables;
```

showed the tables I imported.  However, when I try to change the root user name using

```
update user set user='SomeNewName' where user='root';
```

I get the error message

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'DBName.user' doesn't exist
```

Comment: But does table `DBName` exist when you run `show tables`?

Comment: No.  DBName is the name of a database.  Do I need to create a table of that name, or DBName.user, as well?  What attributes should I put in the table?  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Are you trying to update the actual mysql username?

Comment: Yes.  I am trying to change the root user name to something that is not 'root'.  It is recommended as a security measure.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your MySQL service/daemon?

Comment: You question is too unspecific! Provide details of the actual DB structure AFTER the import!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change a MySQL username you should use [`RENAME USER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-user.html)

```
RENAME USER root@localhost TO other_user@localhost
```

Comment: That worked!  I was obviously using the wrong command.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The table you want to update -- `user`, in this case -- is not within your database (which I assume is called `DBName`, here). The database you need is, in fact, simply called `mysql`.

You can work around this in a few ways:

1. Run your update on `mysql.user` instead of `user`.
2. `use mysql` before you do the update.
3. Use the supplied `RENAME` keyword to do the job instead, as @ExplosionPills suggests.

I'd suggest always taking approach #3 for user management unless you know for sure you're trying to do something the built-in commands can't handle. Chances are, you're not -- and if you are, you'll know it.